# PHP while loop dynamic rowspan

Tags: php, while-loop, html-table

Consider a table for example

[image]

using these table I just wanted to print a table like these by adding rowspan to item id 1002.

[image]

Here is my PHP code

```
$temp_val = '';
$counter = 1;
$sql_sel = mysqli_query($con,"select * from item_table");
while($res_sel = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_sel)){

    if($temp_val == $res_sel['item_id']){
        $counter++;
        echo "<tr></tr>";
    }
    else{
       echo "<tr><td rowspan='".$counter."'>".$res_sel['item_id']."</td></tr>"; 
    }

    $temp_val = $res_sel['item_id'];

}
echo "</table>";
```

it's not correct, it's adding rowspan to item id 1003

Comment: You already asked this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816416/dynamic-row-span-php-while-loop/38817292#38817292.

Comment: @Jasir, check my ans

Comment: maybe interesting? An answer I did - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028866/how-to-merge-table-row-with-php-array.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do like this because when you create the first row then you have to decide how much will this column can span so you have to get the count of the similar ids first to achieve it. I am just giving you and idea how it can work with and array like you database provides.

```
<?php

// Array comming from database
$databaseValues = [
    [
        'item_id'=>'1001',
        'item_color'=>'black',
    ],
    [
        'item_id'=>'1002',
        'item_color'=>'blue',
    ],
    [
        'item_id'=>'1002',
        'item_color'=>'green',
    ],
    [
        'item_id'=>'1003',
        'item_color'=>'red',
    ]
];

// Creating an array as per the need for the table
$arrayForTable = [];
foreach ($databaseValues as $databaseValue) {
    $temp = [];
    $temp['item_color'] = $databaseValue['item_color'];
    if(!isset($arrayForTable[$databaseValue['item_id']])){
        $arrayForTable[$databaseValue['item_id']] = [];
    }
    $arrayForTable[$databaseValue['item_id']][] = $temp;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1">
    <?php foreach ($arrayForTable as $id=>$values) :
        foreach ($values as $key=>$value) :?>
    <tr>
        <?php if($key == 0) :?>
        <td rowspan="<?= count($values)?>"><?= $id?></td>
        <?php endif;?>
        <td><?= $value['item_color']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;
    endforeach; ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will be helpfull for you

Answer (score 0):

You should switch the code inside `else` and `if` statement

Comment: Try placing the code `<td><td rowspan=...` inside the if statement